# Temporarily store text from a dynamic location in the DOM in a javascript variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, variables

I'm building a website for a school assignment, so it's kind of simple. Please excuse or correct any incorrect terminology.

I have multiple identical div's , all sharing the same class, each of these has two paragraph elements in them with some some text in each.

Triggered by a click, I want the specific div I clicked on to be assigned an id for reference in a variable, which should store some text from a child paragraph. I am trying to make a div appear, and the text to be pulled in from the variable.

This is the Javascript I have written:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Hide the overlay.
    $('#overlay_align').hide()

    //Fade in the overlay and change the title.
    $('.object').click(function(){
        //Sets the clicked item to have an id "active", for use in the variable "title".
        $(this).attr("id", "active")
        //Gets the text from this item's title section.
        var title = $('#active:nth-child(2)').text()
        //Sets the title printed in the overlay to whatever the title of the clicked item was.
        $('#overlay_title').html(title)
        console.log( title )
        $('#overlay_align').fadeIn("fast");
    })

    //Fade out the overlay.
    $('#close').click(function(){
        $('#overlay_align').fadeOut("fast")
        //remove the id for reuse when another item is clicked.
        $('#active').removeAttr("id");
    });
});
```

And the relevant part of the HTML document:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Stylesheet.css"/>
<!--jQuery 1.4.2-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--Overlay on click-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Overlay.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="overlay_align">
    <div id="overlay">
        <div id="overlay_left">
        <img id="overlay_img" src=""/>
            <img id="loading" src="../Loading.gif" width="50" height="50" style="margin-top:50%"/>
        </div>
        <div id="overlay_right">
            <p id="overlay_title"></p>
            <img id="close" src="../Close%20Button.png" width="20" height="20"/>
            <p id="overlay_description"></p>
        </div>
        <div id="overlay_footer">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="object">
    <div class="display"></div>
    <p class="title">Ttile</p>
    <p class="category">Category</p>
</div>
<div class="object">
    <div class="display"></div>
    <p class="title">Ttile</p>
    <p class="category">Category</p>
</div>
<div class="object">
    <div class="display"></div>
    <p class="title">Ttile</p>
    <p class="category">Category</p>
</div>
```

The issue I have is that currently, the variable stores the content of both the paragraphs instead of just the second one, (so it appears as "Title Category", and even that only works with the first div. I'm not fixed on this way of doing it, so I'm open to any other ways of doing this too.

Reputation is preventing me from posting individual links, so heres an imgur album showing the different states it's appearing in: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ptk49.jpg

PS: Is there any way to not have to manually indent every line with four spaces?

Comment: There is a button for indenting code, looks like `{}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking at the wrong element. The selector `#active:nth-child(2)` isn't looking for the second child in the element with `id="active"`, it looks for an element with that id that *is* the second child. You would use `#active p:nth-child(2)` to look for the paragraph inside the element.

However, you will run into a problem as you are adding an id to the element. The second time that you click something you will have that id on two elements, so you will get the text from that element and the text from the previous element. Also, as an id should be unique in the page, you may even get some unexpected behaviour in some browsers.

You don't need to set the id on the element to find it, you already have a reference to it in `this` that you can use. Specify `this` as context, and use the selector `p:nth-child(2)`:

```
$('.object').click(function(){
    //Gets the text from this item's title section.
    var title = $('p:nth-child(2)', this).text()
    //Sets the title printed in the overlay to whatever the title of the clicked item was.
    $('#overlay_title').html(title)
    console.log( title )
    $('#overlay_align').fadeIn("fast");
})
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6D9JD/

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I am answering the question correctly. As per my understanding the problem you are facing is

`var title = $('#active:nth-child(2)').text()`

Instead of looking for the second last child you can find the class title in the corresponding div.

```
var title = $('#active').find('.title'); //Assuming that you have only one title in a single div
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use

```
$('#active:nth-child(2)').children().last().text()
```

instead of

```
$('#active:nth-child(2)').text()
```

Comment: That gives the category instead of the title, and only works when the parent element happens to be the second child of its parent.